# Write/Read bit fields structure to/from file

Tags: qt, bit-fields, qfile, qdatastream

I am trying to write bit fields structure to file and then read it.

For example:

```
typedef struct{
     ushort 
              a:4, 
              b:4, 
              c:4, 
              d:4;
} teststruct;
```

I try to write and read it like this

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &st, const teststruct &a)
{
    st <<a.a << a.b << a.c << a.d;
    return st;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &st, teststruct &a)
{
    st >>a.a >> a.b >> a.c >> a.d;
    return st;
}

teststruct str1, str2;   
str1.a = 1;
str1.b = 0;
str1.c = 1;
str1.d = 0;

QFile f("testfile");
f.open(QFile::WriteOnly);
QDataStream st(&f);

st << str1;
f.close();
f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QDataStream st(&f);   
st >> str2;
f.close();
```

But in `QDataStream::operator>>` I got an error

> error: cannot bind bitfield 'a.teststruct::a' to 'quint16& {aka short
>   unsigned int&}'

What can I do with `>>` operator or maybe there is other way to read data to my structure?

Comment: You cannot have a non-const reference to a bit-field. `QDataStream::operator>>(quint16 &i)` takes the parameter as a non-const reference (as the error message you get shows), that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you should notice that the data saved to file is probably incorrect. So for example, having the following struct:

```
struct BitStruct
{
    uint8_t     b1:4;
    uint8_t     b2:4;
};
```

and the operator written as:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &st, const BitStruct &a)
{
    st <<a.b1 << a.b2;
    return st;
}
```

when you write sample data `BitStruct bits{0x1, 0x2};` to file you will have 2 bytes written. Binary contents of the file would be `0x01 0x02` which is probably not what you want to achieve.

It happens due to the fact that calling `st << a.b1` results in the `b1` field being converted to one of the types handled by `QDataStream` which in this case is most probably `quint8` (you can read more in [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html)).

To fix this behaviour you can modify the `QDataStream::operator<<` implementation to:

```
st.writeRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a), sizeof(BitStruct));
```

On the other hand, to read the data to such structure you should do a similar update in the `QDataStream::operator>>` implementation:

```
st.readRawData(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), sizeof(BitStruct));
```

This would allow to write the structure in a compact manner as intended and read particular bit fields accordingly.

This way you have your whole structure written/read in a single approach and you don't have to worry about further growth of the structure (additional fields) and updating both operator implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the reason you have your bitfield structure is so that its size is that of `ushort` (really `uint16_t`), and passing it around by value is cheap and it takes the minimum space possible. That's an OK reason, so let's go with it.

Do note that the structure's in-memory layout doesn't have anything to do with its on-disk layout! The on-disk layout is determined by how you use the `QDataStream` and its operators. The disk layout as you show it wastes 75% of space - each value takes 16 bits, but it only needs 4:

```
(uint16_t a) (uint16_t b) (uint16_t c) (uint16_t d)
```

The key to fix it is to use intermediate values as an interface between the structure and the data stream.

Thus:

```
QDataStream &operator <<(QDataStream &st, const teststruct &a)
{
    uint8_t v0 = (a.d << 4) | a.c;
    uint8_t v1 = (a.b << 4) | a.a;
    st << v0 << v1;
    return st;
}

QDataStream &operator >>(QDataStream &st, teststruct &a)
{
    uint8_t v0, v1;
    st >> v0 >> v1;
    a.a = v1;
    a.b = v1>>4;
    a.c = v0;
    a.d = v0>>4;
    return st;
}
```

The on-disk layout now wastes no space, and is as follows (using pseudotypes):

```
[(uint4_t d) (uint4_t c)] [(uint4_t b) (uint4_t a)]
```